VBA Macro ONLY working when stepped though (F8) or run in isolation, but not in Auto
I have assigned VBA macro to button in Excel, but they do not work.
The code does work in isolation, and when stepped though without error.
I am at a loss what to do...
All advice welcome..
Thanks
Luke
Option Explicit

Dim iColumn As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim hdr As String
Dim columnsToHide() As Variant

Sub HideSpecificColumnsCAM()
    Call UnhideAllColumns
   
    columnsToHide = Array("Part Number", "Description")

    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For iColumn = 1 To lastColumn
        For i = LBound(columnsToHide) To UBound(columnsToHide)
            hdr = columnsToHide(i)
            If Cells(1, iColumn) = hdr Then
                Cells(1, iColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next iColumn
End Sub

Sub UnhideAllColumns()
    Dim col As Range
    Dim colrange As Range

    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For iColumn = 1 To lastColumn
        Set colrange = WIP.Columns(iColumn)
        colrange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Next iColumn
End Sub

Tested the code by stepping through, all seems fine, but when the macro is activated from within Excel nothing seems to happen.

What do you mean by "from within Excel"?

Only a single one of your Range objects is qualified by a Worksheet reference such that your code will always run with respect to the worksheet that is active in the UI; this won't matter if your code is only run from a button on the active sheet but will always matter when the code is run and the worksheet with the button is not active in the UI.

Expanding on @SpectralInstance comment, you need to know which sheet the code should process.   Is it a specific sheet  (such as WIP) or whatever sheet happens to be active when the code is run?  In either case, quality all ranges with that sheet.

Secondly, using module scoped variables here is dangerous.   They might hold an unexpected value from a previous run of the code.  Instead use locally scoped variables and pass them to subs/functions as required

Thirdly See this re use of Call

How about, instead of Call UnhideAllColumns using WIP.UsedRange.Columns.Hidden=False and discarding entirely UnhideAllColumns()? Also, rather than a nested loop in your main sub, it would be more efficient to use a single loop, either with MATCH() or FIND() to locate your headers.

Note also: End(xlToLeft) skips over hidden columns, so if one or more of the last columns are hidden you will not process them...

Thank you all very much for all the help.

Try this out:
Sub HideSpecificColumnsCAM()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lc As Long, colsToHide, rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or a specific worksheet
    
    lc = RowLastUsedColumn(ws.Rows(1))
    If lc = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing on this row
    
    colsToHide = Array("Part Number", "Description")
    
    Set rng = ws.Cells(1, "A").Resize(1, lc)
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        'hide/unhide according to match on `colsToHide`
        'Match returns an error value when `c.Value` is not in `colsToHide`
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = _
           Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, colsToHide, 0))
    Next c
End Sub

'Find the column number of the last cell with a value on row `rw`
'  Fixes issue with `.End(xlToLeft)` skipping over hidden columns
'  Returns zero if `rw` has no content
Function RowLastUsedColumn(rw As Range) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = rw.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlColumns, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then RowLastUsedColumn = f.Column
End Function

